# auth0 still auto-logs in seamlessly even after calling /logout url

Tags: auth0

Simple problem, I want to login and out of an app with various users to check different app functionality. App is using Auth0 for user management.

I *am* calling the /v2/logout url as a part of my flow.

But somehow, after logging out, when I login again the seamless SSO behavior runs and I'm immediately logged in again with no prompts -- it's as if the logout URL was never called.

Only way to get a login prompt again, is to clear my browser cache. Is there an auth0 cookie somewhere I need to delete as well? Or am I missing something? I'm reading the seamless SSO docs but don't see anything beyond calling /v2/logout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So turns out, the issue is around *redirecting* the user as opposed to calling the logout url directly. I was using a separate ajax api call to the logout url. However when I use `window.location.replace(logoutUrl)`, the logout actually happens.

From the auth0 docs:

```
To force a logout, redirect the user to the following URL:

https://YOUR_AUTH0_DOMAIN/v2/logout

Redirecting the user to this URL clears all single sign-on cookies set by Auth0 for the user.
```

So a separate call doesn't work -- have to redirect. Which I suppose makes sense -- a separate ajax call doesn't have the user session context.

Answer (score 1):

Calling the Auth0 `/v2/logout` API [endpoint](https://auth0.com/docs/logout) will log the user out of Auth0 and optionally the IdP (if you specify `federated` parameter). It will not log out the user from your Application so you will need to implement that in your application.

Here in the Javascript SPA [example](https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/spa/vanillajs/01-login#handle-authentication-tokens), in the `setSession()` we are storing the Access token(along with its expiry) and the ID token in localStorage. In the `logout()` function we are then removing these entries. This is logging out from the Application user session. You can optionally redirect to `/v2/logout` to clear the Auth0 and IdP session as well in this function. That way, when you are checking if user is authenticated, the `isAuthenticated()` returns false and we force the user log in again.